# How to delete files using grep?

Tags: files, grep, delete, mariadb

Here the result of this command :

```
sudo dpkg -l | grep mariadb
```

It returns me this :

```
ic  mariadb-server-10.3                        1:10.3.23+maria~bionic                           amd64        MariaDB database server binaries
```

and I need to delete all `mariadb` files. What is the next command line that I should run?

Thank for your help.

Comment: You want to use `apt` to remove the package.  See [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/118880/420428) for nuances

Answer (score 0):

```
$ for package in $( sudo dpkg -l | grep mariadb | awk ' $1 == "ic" { print $2 }' ); do apt remove "$package"; done
```

Comment: I have an issue while trying to remove this mariadb-server-10.3 

output : 
 mariadb-server-10.3
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: What are you hoping `$!` will evaluate to in that awk script? It'll produce a syntax error.

Comment: It was a typographical error, it was supposed to be `$1`.  It and the `$1` which should have been `$2` have been corrected.