# Searching for rootkits with chkrootkit return unexpected results

Tags: debian, terminal, chkrootkit

I ran the [rootkit program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chkrootkit) after his suggestion and noticed something on 1 line that said

> Searching for Linux.Xor.DDoS ...     INFECTED: Possible Malicious Linux.Xor.DDoS installed          /tmp/RustDesk/ipc.pid

Is there anything to be worried about?

Do I have to change something? Or do something to get it fixed?

1. Before trying to remove RustDesk using sudo apt remove RustDesk

   [image]
2. After running sudo apt remove RustDesk, I noticed 1 more line that said

   > ```
   > Checking `lkm'...                                            OooPS, not expected 309900 value
   > chkproc: Warning: Possible LKM Trojan installed
   > ```

   [image]

Comment: Yes, I had installed RustDesk. I will try uninstalling it.

Comment: Edit - Hi Pablo, I tried removing RustDesk using this command - sudo apt remove RustDesk and ran rootkit again. But it is still showing that line. Can you please help me?

Comment: Remove the.pid file.

Comment: Hi GAD3R, can you please tell me what is the command to remove that file?

Comment: All static analysis tools emit "false positives", which is why one should perform investigation before action. For instance, `ls -l /tmp/RustDesk/ipc.pid; file /tmp/RustDesk/ipc.pid; less /tmp/RustDesk/ipc.pid;sudo lsof /tmp/RustDesk/ipc.pid`.

Comment: Thank you for the help @PabloA and @waltinator!

Answer (score 0):

It may be related to [RustDesk being marked as a Trojan](https://github.com/rustdesk/rustdesk/discussions/2485). To remove all those files:

```
sudo rm -rf /tmp/RustDesk/
```

But before that you could:

```bash
ls -l /tmp/RustDesk/ipc.pid     # Get the file properties
file /tmp/RustDesk/ipc.pid      # determine the file type
less /tmp/RustDesk/ipc.pid      # read it
sudo lsof /tmp/RustDesk/ipc.pid # which process has the file currently locked
```

Never trust/run commands blindly, do your own research.

Also, if you installed [RustDesk](https://github.com/rustdesk/rustdesk/releases) with a deb package notice the [difference on `apt` between `remove` and `purge`/`remove --purge`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/118880/209677) (the later will remove about *everything* regarding the package).

Comment: Thank you for the help @Pablo A :)

Comment: @BrendonGomes If you believe this answer your question please mark it as accepted